# Is this possible with an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Sorry for the generic title of the question, but I didn't know how else to put it.. So here goes:

I have a single table that holds the following information:

```
computerName | userName |           date          | logOn | startUp
             |          |                         |       |
ID_000000001 |  NULL    | 2012-08-14 08:00:00.000 |  NULL |   1
ID_000000001 |  NULL    | 2012-08-15 09:00:00.000 |  NULL |   0
ID_000000003 | user02   | 2012-08-15 19:00:00.000 |   1   |  NULL
ID_000000004 | user02   | 2012-08-16 20:00:00.000 |   0   |  NULL
```

computername and username are self-explanatory I suppose

`logOn` is `1` when the user logged on at the machine and `0` when he logged off.

`startUp` is `1` when the machine was turned on and `0` when it got turned off.

the other entry is alway `NULL` respectively since we can't login and startup at the exact same time.

Now my task is: Find out which computers have been turned on the least *amount of time* over the last month (or any given amount of time, but for now  let's say one month) Is this even possible with SQL? <-- Careful: I don't need to know how many times a PC was turned on, but how many hours/minutes each computer was turned on over the given timespace

There's two little problems as well:

We *cannot* say that the first entry of each computer is a `1` in the `startUp` column since the script that logs those events was installed recently and thus maybe a computer was already running when it started logging.

We *cannot* assume that if we order by `date` and only show the `startUp`column that the entries will all be alternating 1's and 0's because if the computer is forced shut down by pulling the plug for example there won't be a log for the shutdown and there could be two 1's in a row.

EDIT: `userName` is of course NULL when `startUp` has a value, since turning on/shutting down doesn't show which user did that.

Comment: MS SQL-Server 2008 sorry, forgot about that.

Comment: When you have the force shut down case, thus two following 1 in the startup column, what do you want to do ? You consider it was always up ?

Comment: @LaGrandMere because we assume that this case is very rare we would, for now, consider it was always up, so basically we only need to count the time it was shut down (between a 0 and the next 1).

Comment: @Octoshape with a single query, it doesn't sound simple. I gave you a solution with a stored procedure, since you're in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a stored procedure, with cursors and fetch loops.
 And you use a temptable to store by computername the uptime.
 I give you the main plan, I'll let you see for the details in the [TSQL guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Another link: a [good example with TSQL Cursor](http://www.jackdonnell.com/articles/SQL_CURSOR.htm).

```
 DECLARE @total_hour_by_computername    
declare @computer_name varchar(255)
declare @RowNum int

 --Now in you ComputerNameList cursor, you have all different computernames:
declare ComputerNameList cursor for
select DISTINCT computername from myTable

-- We open the cursor
OPEN ComputerNameList

     --You begin your foreach computername loop :
    FETCH NEXT FROM ComputerNameList 
    INTO @computer_name
    set @RowNum = 0 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

     SET @total_hour_by_computername=0;

     --This query selects all startup 1 dates by computername order by date.
     select @current_date=date from myTable where startup = 1 and computername = @computername order by date

         --You use a 2nd loop on the dates that were sent you back: 

         --This query gives you the previous date 
         select TOP(1) @previousDate=date from myTable 
         where computername = @computername and date < @current_date and startup is not null
         order by date DESC


         --If it comes null, you can decide not to take it into account.
         --Else
         SET @total_hour_by_computername=@total_hour_by_computername+datediff(hour, @previousDate, @current_date);

    --Once all dates have been parsed, you insert into your temptable the results for this computername

    INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE(Computername,uptime) VALUES (@computername,@total_hour_by_computername)

--End of the @computer_name loop
  FETCH NEXT FROM ComputerNameList 
    INTO @computer_name
END
CLOSE ComputerNameList
DEALLOCATE ComputerNameList
```

You only need a select into your temptable to determine which one of the computers has been up the most time.

Comment: Thanks for this, how do I implement a foreach loop with SQL syntax? a simple while over the IDs of the table?

Comment: @Octoshape I edited my answer and gave the first CURSOR loop to you.

Comment: @Octoshape did you succeed wirting your stored procedure ?

Comment: no I wasn't able to do that yet, I'm still missing some permissions on the database, and we can't find the `CREATE PROCEDURE` permissions on our SQL server :-/ They all seem to be quite new to the whole SQL stuff here.

Comment: @Octoshape GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO myUser; GO

Comment: It's my last day here today, and another guy is gonna carry on the task, but I'm sure this would have worked the best, so I'll check yours as the right answer. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Octoshape Ok thanks, and good luck for your next job then :)

Answer (score 1):

You could group by computer, and use where to filter for startups in a particular month:

```
select  computerName
,       count(*)
from    YourTable
where   '2012-08-01' <= [date] and [date] < '2012-09-01' 
        and startup = 1
group by
        computerName
order by
        count(*) desc
```

Comment: sorry I think it's very ambigously written: I need to know the amount of time each computer has been turned on, not the amount of times <-- note the difference :) so using DATEDIFF or something similar

Answer (score 1):

As RoadWarrior pointed out, an accurate reports is not possible when shutdown messages are dropped. But here is an attempt to generate something useful. I'm going to assume the table name is `computers`:

```
SELECT c1.computerName,
       timediff(MIN(c2.date), c1.date) as upTime
FROM computers as c1, computers as c2
WHERE c1.computerName=c2.computerName
  AND c1.startUp=1 AND c2.startUp=0
  AND c2.date >= c1.date
GROUP BY c1.date
ORDER BY c1.date;
```

This will generate a list of all the periods a computer was on. To generate your requested report you can use the above query as a subquery:

```
SELECT
  c3.computerName,
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(c3.upTime))) AS totalUpTime
FROM
  (SELECT c1.computerName,
          timediff(MIN(c2.date), c1.date) AS upTime
   FROM computers AS c1, computers AS c2
   WHERE c1.computerName=c2.computerName
     AND c1.startUp=1 AND c2.startUp=0
     AND c2.date >= c1.date
   GROUP BY c1.date
   ORDER BY c1.date
  ) AS c3
GROUP BY c3.computerName
ORDER BY c3.totalUpTime;
```

Comment: `c2.date >= c1.date` is not strong enough. If the computer was turned on/off 4 times, you'd get 4*3*2*1 rows.  The query has to search for the first off after an on, not for all of them.

Comment: but it does. It groups these results and takes the minimum of them.

Comment: I get an error: `'timediff' is not a recognized built-in function name.` Should it be datediff? but that required 3 params

Comment: You're right.  I had already voted for your answer.  Side note: `order by` is not usually allowed in a subquery unless you're using `top` or `limit`, you could remove it.

Comment: My example was written/tested using MySQL. Now I see you're using SQL-Server which I'm unfamiliar with. Maybe someone can refine my answer?

Comment: I was able to replace `timediff` with `datediff(minute, start_date, end_date` but there's a part in the first code block that I don't understand: In the end you wrote: `GROUP BY c1.date ORDER BY c1.date` what is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query (replace `table_name` with the name of your table):

```
SELECT SUM(startUp) AS startupTimes 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY computerName
ORDER BY startupTimes
```

This will output the number of times each computer has been started. To get just the first row (the computer that has the least amount of startups) you can append `LIMIT 1` to the query.

Comment: sorry I think it's very ambigously written: I need to know the amount of time each computer has been turned on, not the amount of times <-- note the difference :) so using DATEDIFF or something similar

Answer (score 0):

If (per your last paragraph) you aren't recording all shutdown events. then you don't have the information available to generate a report showing the amount of time each computer has been switched on. Because you aren't recording all instances of computer shutdown, it doesn't matter what SQL query you use.

FWIW, this schema isn't 3NF. A more common approach would be to have a single column recording  each event, for example:

ComputerId:UserId:EventId:EventDate

The first three columns are each a foreign key into another table where the details are stored. Although even with this schema, the UserID would be null for startup/shutdown events.

Comment: you're right, well I didn't make the script :/ I was only put to the task to generate reports out of that table, and yes, the userID's are null for startup/shutdown events, I'll edit that

Comment: well the report won't be very accurate but we've decided to simply consider a computer being turned on until the next shutdown. So I basically only have to count the time between a 0 and a 1 in the `startUp` column